# Can I see which weapon upgrades I own at any time?

Tags: mass-effect-3

*"I'm Commander Shepard, and this is my favorite store on the Citadel"*

I've just entered the Citadel Mall / Shopping Area, and I'm wandering around looking at all the stuff to buy.  There's a couple weapon mods that I think I'd like, but I don't want to buy them if I already own that mod on the Normandy.

**Is there a list of weapon mods that I already own which I can look at before committing to buy new mods at a store?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to buy something you already own in Mass Effect 3.

If you see it available for purchase, you don't own it. (Or that *level* of it)

Alternatively, if you do your purchasing from the Normandy's Shuttle Bay, you're right next to a weapon bench (you can do the same in the Spectre firing range) to check manually.

Answer (score 3):

Any mod that has a level greater than one indicates you already own it. However if you already own a mod, you can level it up by purchasing it or finding it during missions.

Answer (score 1):

You can only buy higher levels of mods you already own, you can never have multiplies

Sources: Personal Expirience.